# Generic class definition: type parameter's type parameter used in abstract methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm not sure at all what keywords to use here, but:
I am trying to make generic base classes for entities and collections, and do not know how to pass on the `KeyType` type to `EntityCollection`'s abstract methods. The question marks hilight the problem parts.

```
public abstract class Entity<KeyType> {
        public KeyType id;
        public Entity(KeyType id) {
                this.id = id;
        }
}

public class Product: Entity<string> {} // Product has a string identifier

public abstract class EntityCollection<EntityType> : Where EntityType:Entity<?> {
        public abstract EntityType Get(?keytype? id);
        public abstract void Add(EntityType entity);
        public abstract IEnumerable<EntityType> GetAll();
}

public class Inventory : EntityCollection<Product> {
        public Product Get(?keytype? id) { ... }
        public void Add(Product item) { ... }
        ...
}

....

var productCode = "12345";
var list = new Inventory();
list.Add(new Product(productCode));
var foundproduct = list.Get(productCode);
```

Am i looking at this from the wrong angle, or missing something?
I could do `EntityCollection<EntityType,KeyType> : Where EntityType:Entity<KeyType>`, but i feel the information is already there in the definitions and thats just duplicating it and making the definitions too complicated.

(the actual code has also interfaces, i tried to make this short)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solving this is to realise that more type information is needed for `EntityCollection` so that you can specify the type where you have ?'s:

```
public abstract class EntityCollection<EntityType, T> where EntityType : Entity<T>
    {
        public abstract EntityType Get(T id);
        public abstract void Add(EntityType entity);
        public abstract IEnumerable<EntityType> GetAll();
    }
```

`Inventory` then becomes:

```
public class Inventory : EntityCollection<Product, string>
{
    public override Product Get(string id) { ... }
    public override void Add(Product item) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is actually how i solved the problem at the moment, it just seemed too cumbersome that you have to tell the compiler again that product's type parameter is the 'string'

Comment: @tonsteri, It would be handy at times if `T` for `Entity<T>` could be inferred by the compiler, but unfortunately C# generics do not work that way and so it must be specified as a type parameter. The simple rule around inferring types is that if all types can be inferred, they need not be specified, but if even one has to be explicitly declared, then all types must be explicitly declared, even if some could be inferred.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input, i'll mark this as accepted and carry on making complicated class declarations :)